# brute force polynomial evaluation algorithm javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, algorithm, math

**what is required is a brute force algorithm, and not some other!**

I'm trying to implement the brute force method for a polynomial in javascript, but an error occurs, the answer is different from the other method above (horner method) - this method is checked and it gives the correct answer
but here is the second brut force- method that gives an excellent result, which is not correct.

What is the error in my code?

input :

> _x = 6 _n = 5 polyEval = [2,3,5,-6,2]

output Horner method:

> 3386 // good. correct answer

output Bruforce method:

> 1496 // bad. incorrect answer

```
class Programm {
    
      constructor(x:number, n:number) {
           this._x = 4;
           this._n = 5;
           this.polyEval =  [2,3,5,-6,2] //this.RandomArray(this._n);
    }
    
      private _x:number;
      private _n:number;
      private polyEval:number[] = [];
```

//working method

```
      private Horner(poly:number[], n:number, x:number){
    
        let time = performance.now();
    
        let result = poly[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < n; i++){
                result = result * x + poly[i];
        }
        time = performance.now() - time;
        console.log("Method: Horner |" ,`Result: ${result}, array: ${this.polyEval} |` ,`time: ${time.toFixed(5)}`);
      }
```

// method with an error that I can't find

```
      private BruteForce(poly:number[], n:number, x:number){
    
        let time = performance.now();
    
        let p: number = 0;
        for(let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
          let coefficient = 1;
          for(let j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            coefficient = coefficient * x;
          }
          p = p + poly[i] * coefficient;
        }
        time = performance.now() - time;
        console.log("Method: Brute Force |" ,`Result: ${p}, array: ${this.polyEval} |` ,`time: ${time.toFixed(5)}`);
      }
```

// generate random array

```
      private RandomArray(n: number):number[]{
        let result:number[] = new Array(n);
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
          if(Math.round(Math.random() * 1) > 0){
            result[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
          }else{
            result[i] = Math.floor(((Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1) * -1);
          }
        }
        return result;
      }
    
      public Main() {
        console.log(`n - array length: ${this._n} | x - coefficient: ${this._x}`);
        this.Horner(this.polyEval, this._n, this._x);
        this.BruteForce(this.polyEval, this._n, this._x);
      }
    }
    const random_N:number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1)) + 3;
    const random_X:number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1)) + 2;
    const poly = new Programm(random_N, random_X);
    poly.Main();
```

Comment: If you haven't noticed, then I have such a solution. but I need exactly the option with brute force ...

Comment: Notice the order how the polynomial is defined. You need to use `poly[n-1-i] * coefficient`. Btw, the terminology needs revising -- the array `poly[]` contains the polynomial coefficients, while what you currently call `coefficient` is the power of the _variable_ or _indeterminate_ x. (I don't know if _x^i_ has a name).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't really understand why

Comment: Please review the answer... It should clarify why it needs to be reversed

Answer (score 0):

The Horner's scheme works like this:

```
 // initially
 result = poly[0] == p_0;

 // iteration 1
 result = result * x + poly[1] == p_0 * x + p_1

 // iteration 2
 result = result * x + poly[2] == (p_0 * x + p_1) * x + p_2
   == p_0 * x^2 + p_1 * x + p_2
```

Thus, the polynomial coefficients in the array `poly` are in order of highest to lowest. Then to replicate that in the brute force solution, one needs to apply the formula as

```
 result = sum(poly[i] * pow(x, n-1-i))  ==

 result = sum(poly[n-1-i] * pow(x, i))
```